# commands / package for target-group-specific creation of documents

Tags: conditionals, include

Is there a package that allows me to create target-group-specific documents.

Basically I have two scenarios:

1. There is an exercise document and each task is initially followed by a solution. In that case I used a self-defined command:

   ```
   \newcommand{\solution}[1]{{\textcolor{red}{\emph{#1}}}}
   %\renewcommand{\solution}[1]{}
   ```

   I simply switch the comment depending on the result I want to have. However, this doesn't work if `\solution`includes a `begin...end` block.

   *Bringing `\solution` to mute all included content would already be sufficient.*
2. There is also a manuscript which includes sections for different groups. I could move each section to a single document and then include them again, but how can I do this depending on a variable etc.?

   Assume 7 sections. For target-group A I want to have sections 1-3 and 5, for B all except 1.

**Edit:** Maybe I was too focused to find a package which solves 1. and 2. in parallel. Thanks to Christian Hupfer for pointing that out. However, in my opinion none of the packages he mentioned (answers, exsheets, probsoln and exams) solves the 2nd problem or at least I don't understand how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `answers`, `exsheets`, `probsoln` and `exams`? One of the most frequent asked questions here! I wished I could recommend you my own package, but it's still not finished :-(

Comment: You're right, maybe I was too stupid to analyze this easy package or too focused to find a package which solves 1. and 2. in parallel. However, in my opinion none of these packages solves the 2nd problem or at least I don't understand how.

Comment: I see that every author has his/her own interpretations/design requests and no package will fit your needs, except of writing it of your own. I don't catch what you mean by group, however. Perhaps I could provide a very 'limited' solution with a a boilt-down version of my (hidden) package

Comment: In one particular example different target-groups are just different courses having each a different focus on the same overall topic. So I have to provide different details (sections) to different groups.

Comment: How is the `task` environment/command? Are you willing to change?

Comment: Can you show us an working example of your setup? This would be really helpful